# Using SSRS in ASP.NET 1.1

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, asp.net-1.1

Is it possible to use SSRS for reports in an ASP.NET 1.1 application? Is there a report viewer control for ASP.NET 1.1? If not is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you can get around it is to use the querystring commands that Reporting Services makes available and serve up the reports in PDF format (or in any of the other deliverable formats to the end user).

Reporting Services itself requires .NET 2.0 to run on its own, so there is no actual controller for displaying the reports live on a website that is only .NET 1.1

Edit: Here is the MSDN information concerning URL Access.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms153586.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms153563.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I have used the report viewer control, but have not found it very useful the majority of the time.  Depending on what you are trying to accomplish, you can access the reports directly via a URL.  You can even do this with passing parameters to the report.

**For example...**
http://reports.mycompany.com/reportserver?%2fMyCompany%2fProject+Folder%2fReportName&EndDate=2/21/2009&BeginDate=2/15/2009&rs%3aParameterLanguage=en-US&rc:parameters=true

The other option that is available is to use the web service that is part of reporting services.  You can then render back the bytes of the report in different formats (PDF, word, Excel...) and output those to the user for download.  I can give you more information on the web service if that is the route you are looking at...

Comment: Hey Rich...  Sometimes it helps to see how the URL is formatted buddy!

Comment: @Russel: That may be true, but you will have to find a way to do that without wrecking the site layout.

Comment: What site layout is being wrecked?  It shows up just fine for me on Firefox.

Comment: @Rich I think you may be missing the point of Russell's post. He is trying to give an example of a URL that would be used to accomplish what the OP was trying to accomplish, thus it is important that the link be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the Report Server through the web service interface from asp.net 1.1.  Add a web reference to your project and then call the various web methods exposed by the report server to render your reports in one of the available formats.  For example, if you render the report in HTML format, you can inject the HTML into a Literal control for display on your web page.  You don't get the advantage of the report viewer's interface for selecting parameter values, paging and exporting, but it should be possible to create a page that mimics those functions.

Comment: Good Call!  The more I use the webservice, the more I like it.